# Make a button that rerenders FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, html, dom, fullcalendar

So I've tried making an HTML input with, like this:

`<input type="checkbox" onclick="calendar.rerenderEvents()">`

But obviously it is unable to reach the method. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Edit: I'm using version 4.0.0-beta.4

Comment: Why do you need a separate button to re-render events? This doesn't actually do anything useful unless you have made some other out-of-band change to the calendar or its data. Perhaps you meant refetchEvents, to get new data from the server? And why a checkbox? That should be used for a yes/no decision, not a simple command which is always the same. It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: But anyway you can achieve the basic idea quite simply using addEventListener. Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hnu6y5v0/1/ (I used a made-up "calendar" object but it doesn't matter - the point is that it must have higher scope than the event handler function, so that it's accessible when the handler runs).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for providing a demo, as @decod-decod already suggested this but I did it wrong. I didn't know you had to declare function(), I just put calendar.rerenderEvents() directly into the event listener. If you could clarify as to why it is this way, I'd really appreciate it. Once again, thank you so much.

As for why a checkbox, I'm making categories, so that when a user unchecks a box it will rerender without that category of events. Hopefully my explanation was alright.

Comment: One more thing (sorry), could you also clarify why querySelector is needed, and why getElementById doesn't work?

Comment: " I didn't know you had to declare function(), I just put calendar.rerenderEvents() directly into the event listener.". Well you don't _have_ to do it that way. Since rerenderEvents doesn't require any parameters you can just make it the target of the event handler directly: https://jsfiddle.net/h4a8pqcd/ (just remember to remove the `()` so it passes a reference to the function which can be used later, and doesn't just execute it immediately the handler is declared)

Comment: querySelector isn't _needed_, it's just one way of doing it. It's the newer way in recent versions of JS. It accepts a CSS selector rather than a simple ID. So it accepts the selector "#rerender" (just like you'd use in a CSS file) rather then just "rerender", which is what document.getElementById requires. querySelector can accept other selectors as well (e.g. class or attribute, or any other valid CSS selector, so it's more flexible than just targeting the ID. However you're right, in this scenario, either would work as long as you pass the right value: https://jsfiddle.net/h4a8pqcd/1/

Comment: Good stuff. Thank you for all your help. Seems I've got a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this more easily using an unobtrusive event handler (created using the `addEventListener` function - it can then refer to an instance of `calendar` which has a higher scope within the script block:

```js
//dummy "calendar" object for the purpose of the demo
var calendar = {
  rerenderEvents: function() {
    alert("X");
  }
}

document.querySelector("#rerender").addEventListener("click", function() {
  calendar.rerenderEvents();
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="rerender" /><label for="rerender">Re-Render</label>
```

(I used a made-up "calendar" object but it doesn't matter - the point is that it must have higher scope than the event handler function, so that it's accessible when the handler runs.)

Answer (score 0):

hide fullcalendar when the button is clicked changed the fullcalendar from display:hidden to display:block

Comment: I like the idea, unfortunately it didn't work though.

Comment: maybe use an eventlistener instead of an on click event, use queryselector or another error is doing some code in the js instead of useing 2 dif clases and cheanging the class useing .classname = "" those are some of the comon mistakes :)

Comment: This works, thanks for your help :) I just needed a demo to figure out how it works.

Answer (score -1):

input type="checkbox" onclick="calendar.rerenderEvents()">